# unknown property while using a list of class in Vf page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i have a class

```
public with sharing class CAccountRep {
string sageAccountNo {get;set;}
string clientName {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}
integer noofdays {get;set;}
string billableUnits {get;set;}
decimal dailyChargeRate {get;set;}
string nominalCode {get;set;}
string practice {get;set;}
string taxFlag {get;set;}
string ProjectId {get;set;}
string PONumber {get;set;}

public CAccountRep(String CrSageAc,String CrClientN,string CrName,integer Crnoofdays,string crbillableunits,decimal CrDecimalChargeRate,string crNominalCode,string CrPractice, String CrTaxFlag,String CrProjectId, String CrPONumber)
{
    sageAccountNo=CrSageAc;
    clientName=CrClientN;
    name=CrName;
    noofdays=Crnoofdays;
    billableUnits=crbillableunits;
    dailyChargeRate=CrDecimalChargeRate;
    nominalCode=crNominalCode;
    practice=CrPractice;
    taxFlag=CrTaxFlag;
    ProjectId=CrProjectId;
    PONumber=CrPONumber;

}

    }
```

Iam creating a object of this class and passing out the parameters into this class

```
   public List<CAccountRep> AR { get;set; }

   public list<CAccountRep> getAR()
   {   
    if(AR!= null)
        return AR ;
    else return null;
   }

   Using the follwing code to create the object of the class

     CAccountRep CRep=new CAccountRep(projectList[0].Sage_Account_Number__c,projectList[0].Client_Name__c, Cname,enoOfBillableDays,projectList[0].BillableUnits__c,AssConlist[0].Daily_Charge_Rate_of_Consultant__c,AssConlist[0].Nominal_Code__c,projectList[0].C85_Practice__c,projectList[0].Tax_Flag__c,projectList[0].Project_ID__c,projectList[0].PO_Number__c);

     AR.add(CRep);
```

In my VF page i am trying to display the contents of the list AR.

But i get an error Unknown Propery CAccountRep.ProjectId  while saving the VF page.

```
<table id="tableRep">
   <apex:repeat id="tc" value="{!AR}" var="TCrep">
   <tr>

   <td>{!TCrep.ProjectId}</td>
   </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
   </table>
```

I can get the output like this if i just give {!TCrep}

```
CAccountRep:[PONumber=null, ProjectId=C85_JPMC1 _A-0083, billableUnits=null, clientName=001A000000YJFhdIAH, dailyChargeRate=null, name=Change Order 10002011-09-05 to 2011-10-10 : 0 null, nominalCode=null, noofdays=0, practice=Administration, sageAccountNo=null, taxFlag=null]
CAccountRep:[PONumber=null, ProjectId=C85_BBCWW _A-0084, billableUnits=null, clientName=001A000000cwgIlIAI, dailyChargeRate=null, name=Secure Desktop v012011-09-05 to 2011-10-10 : 0 null, nominalCode=null, noofdays=0, practice=null, sageAccountNo=null, taxFlag=null]
CAccountRep:[PONumber=null, ProjectId=C85_JPMC1 _A-0083, billableUnits=null, clientName=001A000000YJFhdIAH, dailyChargeRate=null, name=Change Order 10002011-09-05 to 2011-10-10 : 0 null, nominalCode=null, noofdays=0, practice=Administration, sageAccountNo=null, taxFlag=null]
```

Any ideas on how to get it display correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the compiler is getting confused because you have 2 public getters in it's opinion i.e. both of these lines:

```
public List<CAccountRep> AR { get;} // just removed set; for now

public list<CAccountRep> getAR()
```

Would be called from a Visualforce page when you use the following syntax in the page:

```
{!AR}
```

Try doing this instead:

```
public List<CAccountRep> AR { get{
    return AR ; // if AR is null it returns null so the if statement was redundant

}set; }
```

And remove the getAR() method. You should also mark the class member variables that you'd like to be visible as public e.g.

```
public string ProjectId {get;set;}
```

Comment: i removed both the getter methods like you had suggested and added the get and set as you had suggested.. i still get the same error..

Comment: Oh dear...i cant believe i missed out on public modifiers.. Thanks a lot